# how to split a string by curly brackets?

Tags: java

Currently I'm doing a POST method to insert data into database. The flow of the program is will read from the body and read as string. After that, will verify is start from [ or {. If the string is start with [ then will convert to array list and save to the model. Else it will save to the model.
But the problem that I facing now is I don't know how to split the string based on the curly bracket {}.

POST Method:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "insert", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public @ResponseBody String add2(@RequestBody String body) {
        Trips trip = null;
        LOGGER.debug("start insert to database...");    
        if(body.startsWith("[")){
            ArrayList<String> myList = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(body.split("\\[{|}]")));
                
            for(int i=0;i<myList.size();i++){
                System.out.println(i + " " + myList.get(i));
                //tripsService.saveTrips(myList.get(i));
            }
            
            System.out.println( myList.toString());
        }else if(body.startsWith("{")){
            tripsService.saveTrips(trip);
        }
```

Model Class :

```
@Service
@Transactional  
public class TripsService {
    @Autowired
    private TripRepository tripRepository;
    
    public List<Trips> listAllTrips(){
        return tripRepository.findAll();
        
    }
    public void saveTrips(Trips trips) {
        try{
            tripRepository.save(trips);
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public Trips getTrips(Integer id) {
        return tripRepository.findById(id).get();
    }

    public void deleteTrip(Integer id) {
        tripRepository.deleteById(id);
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: The input you are getting seems to be in a format called JSON. You parse JSON using a JSON parser! That is way more reliable, and the handling is much better.

Comment: That's a JSON. Use a JSON parser instead.

Comment: Don't read the body as string and parse the JSON by hand. Write your own DTO class, Spring can handle the deserialization automatically

Comment: You've already been told to use a JSON parser in your other question. Re-posting a new question with the [**exact same text**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66742788/5221149) will just get you the exact same comments, i.e. ***USE A JSON PARSER!!!***

Comment: If you are absolutely bent on **not** using a JSON parser then this **may** get you somewhere you apparently want to be: `String[] stringArray = strg.replaceAll("[\\[\\]]", "").split(",(?![^\\{\\}]*\\})");`

Answer (score 0):

This is a JSON String,you should use JSONArray parser.
Other way,you can use @RequestBody reflect a Object ,like this

```
public @ResponseBody String add2(@RequestBody List<Object>) {
}
```